# Injecting data into <script>var t = {{{$data}}}</script> via server side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Here is the demo:

```
<script>
    var temp = {{{$data}}}
</script>
```

I like inject the $data into the `<script>`, but in the vue2.0 the the {{{}}} is  deprecated, and be insteaded by v-html. And the v-html looks can not inplement the requirment.

Comment: Hey, psst! Here you have a nasty trick: generate the `<script>` tag as a text and then use it in `v-html` :D Anyway, why do you want to generate a JS code with another JS code?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Since the $data come from the back-end, and I need use it in the front-end. If use ajax there will be more one request, so the I like inject it via server-sider rendering. The back-end and front-end both use vue

Comment: What you are trying for, is principially bad idea, with detrimental effect on user interface. Best you can do is restructure your application.

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
<script>
    window.data = <?=$data?>
</script>
```

in vue:

```
var data  = window.data
```